# Command.StatementCompleted get called more than once

Tags: c#, sql, events, sqlcommand

I'm using this when I create a command :

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.StatementCompleted += new StatementCompletedEventHandler(statementCompleted);
```

But my method "statementCompleted" is called more than once for a same command.

Someone have an idea...

Thanks

Comment: What is your sql command text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StatementCompleted event can fire multiple times if the sql you are attempting to run contains more than 1 sql command, such as multiple insert or update entries.

Comment: Thanks got an idea wich event I could use that is called once at the end ?

Comment: Not sure you need to. If you call ExecuteNonQuery or similiar, the next line of code will run (unless SqlException thrown)